# Iterate each value from two lists and then put them into a formula

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Given below is the demo of my data

```
a=[15401.26,15402.32,15403.45,120.3,122.4] #here are 300 such values
b=[1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.7] #here are 300 such values
```

I want to take each value from both the lists and then calculate the given below calculation:

```
nccn= a*0.4**b
print(nccn)
```

Given below is my code

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
a=15401.54
b=1.2106
nccn= a*0.4**b
print(nccn)
```

1]How to structure the loop for the above issue.
2]Please suggest the additions  in the code.
3]Output expected for each respective corresponding values on separate line one below the other.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using list comprehension

```
[i*0.4**j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

#### Using numpy

```
np.array(a)*0.4**np.array(b)
```

Example :

```
import numpy as np
a=[15401.26,15402.32,15403.45,120.3,122.4]
b=[1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.7]
# Using list comprehension
print ([i*0.4**j for i,j in zip(a,b)])
# Using numpy
print (np.array(a)*0.4**np.array(b))
```

Output:

```
[5128.94736441207, 4270.415472250151, 3555.608938503435, 23.119243105274588, 25.780029089681708]
[5128.94736441 4270.41547225 3555.6089385    23.11924311   25.78002909]
```

#### Edit 1:

To export the result to csv, you can use pandas (assuming that an additional dependency is ok)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a': a, 'b':b})
df['nccn'] = df['a']*0.4**df['b']
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked very smoothly.

Comment: Also you would need lengths constraint until Python 3.10 will be released where according to PEP 618: "The zip() function now has an optional strict flag, used to require that all the iterables have an equal length." Otherwise you would stuck in some circumstances.

Comment: I have got the output but, I am now wondering how to assign it to a variable so that, I export the output to excel file. Can you please help with this?

Comment: @chinu check the update

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

a=[15401.26,15402.32,15403.45,120.3,122.4]
b=[1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.7]

def MultiplicationArrayElements(a, b):
    if (len(a) == len(b)):
        print ('Lists are equal in length, let\' sbegin...')
        counter = 0
        for i in a:
            print ('A list is: '+str(a[counter])+' | B list is:'+str(b[counter])+' | nccn is: '+str(a[counter]*0.4*b[counter]))
            counter+=1
    else:
        print ('Lists are NOT equal in length, exit...')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MultiplicationArrayElements(a,b)
```